# Java progress bar shows when backend execution completes

Tags: java, user-interface, progress-bar

I am working on some java application. I have to show Jprograss bar in this application. There is some backend execution in login button action which takes 5 to 10 seconds. I want to show progress bar when backend execution is going on .But Jprogress bar works opposite . It show when backend execution complete .. Any idea about this problem .. If yes then how to resolve this
Code is something like this :

```
        f1 = new JFrame();
        JProgressBar pbar = new JProgressBar();
        Jpanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        pbar.setStringPainted(true);
        Timer timer = new Timer(50);
        panel2.add(pbar);
        f1.add(panel2);
        f1.setSize(500, 160);
        f1.setTitle("Conversion Progress");
        f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        export1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent a)
        {   
            f1.setVisible(true);
             timer.start();
            // Some other execution
        }
        });
```

Comment: How are you handling the event on button onClick? I mean the listener class

Comment: I am adding Jprogress bar in another Jframe and setvisible Jframe on button click

Comment: It would be great if you could post your snippet/ snapshot here.